# show user an error in net core web app in the try catch block

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a controller that posts a new game to the server via an API.

That part works, but some reason my email is failing and I want to show the user the error.

So I tried putting a Response.Write in my catch statement like below.

But it can't find a definition for both 'Response.Write' or 'Server'.

How would I go about adding these?

Thanks!

```
   [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ProcessGameForm([FromBody] MakeGame game)
    {         

        ' xx post form code 

       ' now send email alert
       try
        {
            SendMyEmail(game.Title);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('" + Server.HtmlEncode(ex.ToString()) + "')</script>");
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the spirit of this site and in hopes that you're using that code purely for debugging, I'll answer how exactly to get what you're trying to do working, but man... There is **so** much wrong with that code!

In .NET Core there are no more in-context `Response` or `Server` objects.

You would instead have to do something like:

```
await HttpResponseWritingExtensions.WriteAsync(this.Response, "<script>alert('" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(ex.ToString()) + "')</script>");
```

Also I think an even easier (and slightly more correct way) would be:

```
return Content("<script>alert('" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(ex.ToString()) + "');
```

I haven't tested either of the above but it should work.

However, you should really have a proper error page (including for internal use) which will accept an `Exception` object as the model, and then present that however you want using Razor syntax.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your honesty. :)  However, Visual Studio doesn't like HtmlEncode by saying  "No overload for method 'HtmlEncode' takes 0 arguments "

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell Edited!